# SQL Server 2016 slow running procedure with attached plan

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

The stored procedure is running very slow in SQL Server 2016 as compared to SQL Server 2019. It's doing some common validation from a temporary staging table and inserting data in primary tables and mapping tables.

The mapping tables have clustered indexes on primary keys {Table1Id, Table2Id, Table3Id}. The procedure needs to process around 4 million rows. It finishes execution in 2 hours in SQL Server 2019, but takes probably 6-8 hours in SQL Server 2016 with the same data file.

Description of the stored proc -

There is a dbo.HouseholdTemp table with all rows to be processed its doing

1. Slice each row and insert one portion in dbo.Locations and another
   potion in dbo.Individuals table if LocationGroupId or IndividualGroupId
   does not exists or is empty.
2. Save the generated ID from those two tables and map them in dbo.Households table {LocationId, IndividualId}.
3. Select an existing MailingId from dbo.Mailings table with a JOIN query.
4. Insert another row in dbo.ListTypes table if the combination of Type and Code does not exists and get the ListTypes Id.
5. Insert a row in the dbo.HouseholdMailings table with MailingId,
   LocationId, IndividualId , ListTypeId.

Execution plan is attached.

FYI, The SQL installation is on C drive where as the database files are on D drive. Please help!

Execution plan can be found here : https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BybjNm5a8

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[usp_ProcessHouseholdDatav2]
AS
BEGIN TRY



    -- Declare variables
    DECLARE @DataIngestionLogId int = 0;
    DECLARE @HouseholdCount bigint = 0;
    DECLARE @n int = 0;
    DECLARE @householdrecords int = 0;
    DECLARE @householdrecordsexistscount int = 0;
    DECLARE @householdmailingsrecords int = 0;
    DECLARE @householdmailingsrecordsexistscount int = 0;
    DECLARE @listtyperecords int = 0;
    DECLARE @tempid int = 0;
    DECLARE @locationid int = 0;
    DECLARE @individualid int = 0;
    DECLARE @mailingid int = 0;
    DECLARE @jobnumber nvarchar(6) = N'';
    DECLARE @mergedpanelcode nvarchar(10) = N'';
    DECLARE @locationgroupid nvarchar(10) = N'';
    DECLARE @individualgroupid nvarchar(10) = N'';
    DECLARE @listtype varchar(3) = '';
    DECLARE @listcode varchar(4) = '';
    DECLARE @findernumber nvarchar(50) = N'';
    DECLARE @modelrank nvarchar(2) = N'';
    DECLARE @listtypeid int = 0;
    DECLARE @starttime datetime = GETDATE();

    INSERT INTO dbo.DataIngestionLogs (FileName,
                                       Message,
                                       CreatedDate)
    VALUES ('usp_ProcessHouseholdData', 'PROCESS STARTED ' + CAST(@HouseholdCount AS nvarchar(10)) + ' records to be processed', GETDATE());

    SET @DataIngestionLogId = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

    WHILE EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1 1 FROM dbo.HouseholdTemp ht WHERE ht.ProcessedDate IS NULL /*AND @n < 1000000*/ )
    BEGIN

        --  Retrieve Id, JobNumber and MergedPanelCode from HouseholdTemp table
        SELECT TOP 1
               @tempid = ht.Id,
               @jobnumber = ht.JobNumber,
               @mergedpanelcode = ht.MergedPanelCode,
               @locationgroupid = ht.LocationGroupID,
               @individualgroupid = ht.IndividualGroupID,
               @listtype = ht.ListType,
               @listcode = ht.ListCode,
               @findernumber = ht.FinderNumber,
               @modelrank = ht.ModelRank
        FROM dbo.HouseholdTemp ht
        WHERE ht.ProcessedDate IS NULL;

        IF (@locationgroupid IS NULL OR @locationgroupid = '')
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO dbo.Locations (LocationGroupId,
                                       Address1,
                                       Address2,
                                       City,
                                       State,
                                       Zip10,
                                       ZipCode,
                                       DeliveryPointCode,
                                       FIPSCounty,
                                       CountyName,
                                       AddressType,
                                       PrimaryNumber,
                                       PreDirectional,
                                       StreetName,
                                       StreetSuffix,
                                       PostDirectional,
                                       UnitDesignator,
                                       UnitNumber,
                                       PMBNumber,
                                       CarrierRoute,
                                       PenetrationCode,
                                       MetroName,
                                       CreatedDate,
                                       ModifiedDate)
            SELECT TOP 1
                   ht.LocationGroupID AS LocationGroupID,
                   ht.Address1 AS Address1,
                   ht.Address2 AS Address2,
                   ht.City AS City,
                   ht.State AS State,
                   ht.Zip10 AS Zip10,
                   ht.ZipCode AS ZipCode,
                   ht.DeliveryPointCode AS DeliveryPointCode,
                   ht.FIPSCounty AS FIPSCounty,
                   ht.CountyName AS CountyName,
                   ht.AddressType AS AddressType,
                   ht.PrimaryNumber AS PrimaryNumber,
                   ht.PreDirectional AS PreDirectional,
                   ht.StreetName AS StreetName,
                   ht.StreetSuffix AS StreetSuffix,
                   ht.PostDirectional AS PostDirectional,
                   ht.UnitDesignator AS UnitDesignator,
                   ht.UnitNumber AS UnitNumber,
                   ht.PMBNumber AS PMBNumber,
                   ht.CarrierRoute AS CarrierRoute,
                   ht.PenetrationCode AS PenetrationCode,
                   ht.MetroName AS MetroName,
                   GETDATE(),
                   GETDATE()
            FROM dbo.HouseholdTemp ht
            WHERE ht.Id = @tempid;

            SET @locationid = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
        END;

        ELSE
        BEGIN

            --  Check if record exists with LocationGroupId in Locations table
            IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1
                                   1
                            FROM dbo.Locations l
                            WHERE l.LocationGroupId = RTRIM(LTRIM(@locationgroupid))))
            BEGIN
                --  PRINT 'Location does not exists with LocationGroupId : ' + @locationgroupid + '--> Insert in Locations table....'
                INSERT INTO dbo.Locations (LocationGroupId,
                                           Address1,
                                           Address2,
                                           City,
                                           State,
                                           Zip10,
                                           ZipCode,
                                           DeliveryPointCode,
                                           FIPSCounty,
                                           CountyName,
                                           AddressType,
                                           PrimaryNumber,
                                           PreDirectional,
                                           StreetName,
                                           StreetSuffix,
                                           PostDirectional,
                                           UnitDesignator,
                                           UnitNumber,
                                           PMBNumber,
                                           CarrierRoute,
                                           PenetrationCode,
                                           MetroName,
                                           CreatedDate,
                                           ModifiedDate)
                SELECT TOP 1
                       ht.LocationGroupID AS LocationGroupID,
                       ht.Address1 AS Address1,
                       ht.Address2 AS Address2,
                       ht.City AS City,
                       ht.State AS State,
                       ht.Zip10 AS Zip10,
                       ht.ZipCode AS ZipCode,
                       ht.DeliveryPointCode AS DeliveryPointCode,
                       ht.FIPSCounty AS FIPSCounty,
                       ht.CountyName AS CountyName,
                       ht.AddressType AS AddressType,
                       ht.PrimaryNumber AS PrimaryNumber,
                       ht.PreDirectional AS PreDirectional,
                       ht.StreetName AS StreetName,
                       ht.StreetSuffix AS StreetSuffix,
                       ht.PostDirectional AS PostDirectional,
                       ht.UnitDesignator AS UnitDesignator,
                       ht.UnitNumber AS UnitNumber,
                       ht.PMBNumber AS PMBNumber,
                       ht.CarrierRoute AS CarrierRoute,
                       ht.PenetrationCode AS PenetrationCode,
                       ht.MetroName AS MetroName,
                       GETDATE(),
                       GETDATE()
                FROM dbo.HouseholdTemp ht
                WHERE ht.Id = @tempid;

                SET @locationid = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

            END;

            ELSE
            BEGIN

                SELECT TOP 1
                       @locationid = Id
                FROM dbo.Locations l
                WHERE l.LocationGroupId = RTRIM(LTRIM((@locationgroupid)));

            END;

        END;

        IF (@individualgroupid IS NULL OR @individualgroupid = '')
        BEGIN

            INSERT INTO dbo.Individuals (IndividualGroupId,
                                         FirstName,
                                         LastName,
                                         DateOfBirth,
                                         EmailAddress,
                                         Gender,
                                         MaritalStatus,
                                         CreatedDate,
                                         ModifiedDate)
            SELECT ht.IndividualGroupID AS IndividualGroupId,
                   ht.FirstName AS FirstName,
                   ht.LastName AS LastName,
                   CAST(ht.DateOfBirth AS date) AS DateOfBirth,
                   ht.EmailAddress AS EmailAddress,
                   ht.Gender AS Gender,
                   ht.MaritalStatus AS MaritalStatus,
                   GETDATE(),
                   GETDATE()
            FROM dbo.HouseholdTemp ht
            WHERE ht.Id = @tempid;

            SET @individualid = SCOPE_IDENTITY();

        END;

        ELSE
        BEGIN
            --  Check if record exists with IndividualGroupId in Individuals table
            IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1
                                   1
                            FROM dbo.Individuals i
                            WHERE i.IndividualGroupId = RTRIM(LTRIM((@individualgroupid)))))
            BEGIN

                INSERT INTO dbo.Individuals (IndividualGroupId,
                                             FirstName,
                                             LastName,
                                             DateOfBirth,
                                             EmailAddress,
                                             Gender,
                                             MaritalStatus,
                                             CreatedDate,
                                             ModifiedDate)
                SELECT ht.IndividualGroupID AS IndividualGroupId,
                       ht.FirstName AS FirstName,
                       ht.LastName AS LastName,
                       CAST(ht.DateOfBirth AS date) AS DateOfBirth,
                       ht.EmailAddress AS EmailAddress,
                       ht.Gender AS Gender,
                       ht.MaritalStatus AS MaritalStatus,
                       GETDATE(),
                       GETDATE()
                FROM dbo.HouseholdTemp ht
                WHERE ht.Id = @tempid;

                SET @individualid = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
            END;
            ELSE
            BEGIN

                SELECT TOP 1
                       @individualid = Id
                FROM dbo.Individuals i
                WHERE i.IndividualGroupId = RTRIM(LTRIM(@individualgroupid));

            END;

        END;



        IF (@locationid > 0 AND @individualid > 0)
        BEGIN

            BEGIN TRY
                INSERT INTO dbo.Households (LocationId,
                                            IndividualId,
                                            CreatedDate)
                VALUES (@locationid, @individualid, GETDATE());

                SET @householdrecords = @householdrecords + 1;
            END TRY
            BEGIN CATCH
            END CATCH;
            --  Get Mailing Id from JobNumber and MergedPanelCode

            SELECT TOP 1
                   @mailingid = m.Id
            FROM dbo.Mailings m
                 INNER JOIN dbo.Jobs j ON j.Id = m.JobId
                 INNER JOIN dbo.MergedPanels mp ON mp.Id = m.MergedPanelId
            WHERE j.Number = @jobnumber
              AND mp.Code = @mergedpanelcode;
            IF (@mailingid > 0)
            BEGIN
                IF ((@listtype IS NOT NULL
                  OR @listtype != '')
                AND (@listcode IS NOT NULL
                  OR @listcode != ''))
                BEGIN
                    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT TOP 1
                                          1
                                   FROM dbo.ListTypes lt
                                   WHERE lt.Type = @listtype
                                     AND lt.Code = @listcode)
                    BEGIN
                        INSERT INTO dbo.ListTypes (Type,
                                                   Code,
                                                   CreatedDate,
                                                   ModifiedDate)
                        VALUES (@listtype, @listcode, GETDATE(), GETDATE());

                        SET @listtypeid = SCOPE_IDENTITY();



                        SET @listtyperecords = @listtyperecords + 1;
                    END;
                    ELSE
                    BEGIN
                        SELECT TOP 1
                               @listtypeid = Id
                        FROM dbo.ListTypes lt
                        WHERE lt.Type = @listtype
                          AND lt.Code = @listcode;
                    END;

                END;
                IF (@listtypeid > 0)
                BEGIN TRY
                    INSERT INTO dbo.HouseholdMailings (MailingId,
                                                       LocationId,
                                                       IndividualId,
                                                       ListTypeId,
                                                       FinderNumber,
                                                       ModelRank,
                                                       CreatedDate)
                    VALUES (@mailingid, @locationid, @individualid, @listtypeid, @findernumber, @modelrank, GETDATE());

                    SET @listtypeid = 0;



                    SET @householdmailingsrecords = @householdmailingsrecords + 1;
                END TRY
                BEGIN CATCH
                END CATCH;
            END;
            ELSE
            BEGIN
                SET @householdmailingsrecordsexistscount = @householdmailingsrecordsexistscount + 1;
            END;

        END;

        --  Update the ProcessedDate in HouseholdTemp table

        UPDATE dbo.HouseholdTemp
        SET ProcessedDate = GETDATE()
        WHERE Id = @tempid;

        SET @n = @n + 1;
        SET @locationid = 0;
        SET @individualid = 0;
        SET @mailingid = 0;
    END;

    INSERT INTO dbo.DataIngestionLogs (FileName,
                                       Message,
                                       ParentId,
                                       CreatedDate)
    VALUES ('usp_ProcessHouseholdData', 'PROCESS COMPLETED ' + CAST(@n AS nvarchar(10)) + ' records processed.', @DataIngestionLogId, GETDATE());

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    PRINT 'Error insert...';
    INSERT INTO dbo.DataIngestionErrors
    VALUES (SUSER_SNAME(), ERROR_NUMBER(), ERROR_STATE(), ERROR_SEVERITY(), ERROR_LINE(), ERROR_PROCEDURE(), ERROR_MESSAGE(), GETDATE(), @DataIngestionLogId);

END CATCH;
```

Comment: First things first, stop processing your rows 1 (agonising) row at a time. 2 hours is a long time for a query to, and no wonder. You ***need*** to be using set based solutions. Updating 4 million rows for an RDBMS is pretty trivial, all things considering. If you did want to do it in batches, then 1 million rows a batch would likely easily be able to be handled without the log file getting too large. But one row at a time? No, that's why this is slow.

Comment: I know that whitespace and linebreaks make your code readable, but it's *good* use of it that does that. You had so many line breaks in there, it makes it so much harder. Also, when I formatted your code, you have several` TRY...CATCH`s in there, however, you do nothing in the `CATCH` (it's just `BEGIN CATCH END CATCH`). These are also a really bad idea, as if an error happens you just ignore it. It's just as bad as when people used to just go `ON ERROR RESUME NEXT` in VB. Handling the error is important.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Can you please share an example of how I can batch these in  set based solution ?

Comment: There's a lot going on in your query, if I am honest. What is your goal here, what is the purpose of the process? What about those `TRY...CATCH`s?

Comment: This should all be in your question, not the comments

Comment: Updated the main question.

Comment: Do you need unpredictable rows? Using `top` without `order by`  can provide them. Adding `order by` may impact performance by forcing a sort. Using `top` in an `exists` query doesn't help.

Comment: You may be able to use a pair of `insert`/`select` statements to handle Step 1 by adding `where` clauses to the selects so only new data are inserted and adding an [`output` clause](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) to the inserts to capture both the original data and the newly assigned identity values. Then pursue modifying the code that follows to use the results of the `output` clauses.

Comment: I switched bulk insert using OUTPUT clause. However I am having another hiccup that is mentioned here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62490368/sql-bulk-insert-unique-rows-from-a-parent-table-to-multiple-child-tables?noredirect=1#comment110513891_62490368

Comment: I was able to do it using OUTPUT with bulk insert. Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62490368/sql-bulk-insert-unique-rows-from-a-parent-table-to-multiple-child-tables?noredirect=1#comment110513891_62490368